# logical multiplication of matrices A and B by the operation "AND" and "OR" in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, getchar

This is the question:

> A logical matrix is a matrix in which all its elements are either 0 or
>   1.
>
> We define logical multiplication of matrices A and B by the operation
>   defined below, where "·" is the logical AND operation, and "+" is the
>   logical OR operation.
>
> In this assignment, you will create two 5x5 logical matrices and find
>   the corresponding matrix which will be created from "multiply" these 2
>   matrices
>
> 1. Define global SIZE equals to 5 (Already defined in the template)
> 2. Write a function that gets a matrix reference and reads the input
>      to the matrix from the user. If the input is non-zero replace it by 1.
>      If the user did not enter enough values before the end of the line,
>      the remaining cells in the matrix will be populated with zeros. Also
>      make sure if the user inputs too many characters, you only take what's
>      needed and discard the remaining input. (Eg: 1509 is a 2x2 matrix with
>      values 1101, and ‘1 5 ‘ is also a 2x2 matrix with values 1111, the
>      highlighted whitespace is taken as a 1 as discussed above.)
>
>    Function signature: `void read_mat(int mat[][SIZE])`
> 3. Write a function that multiplies, as defined above, two matrices
>      and enters the results into a third matrix with suitable dimensions.
>
>    Function signature: `void mult_mat(int mat1[][SIZE],int mat2[][SIZE], int result_mat[][SIZE])`
> 4. Write a function that prints a matrix into the screen. Please use
>      “%3d” for printing format to make it look nice as shown below.
>
>    Function signature: `void print_mat(int mat[][SIZE])`
> 5. Write the main program which uses the functions above. The program
>      reads the matrices values from the user, multiplies them and prints
>      the result matrix on the screen.
>
> The function definitions given are intentional with the return
>   statements as void. Do not change them. Arrays are transferred between
>   functions as references rather as primitives like variables. So the
>   function definitions are perfectly valid. Also, there is no limit on
>   the input from the user. You can read only the required digits, and
>   then stop reading, and discard the remaining input.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5

void read_mat(int mat[][SIZE],int size)
{
    int  i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; 
    char c; 
    c=getchar();
    while(c!='\n' && k<size*size){
        if(c!='0'){
            mat[i][j]=1;
            j++;
        }
        else{
            mat[i][j]=0;
            j++;
        }
        if (j >= size){
            j = 0;
            i++;
        }
        if (i >= size){
            return;
        }
        c=getchar();
        k++;
    }
}


void mult_mat(int mat1[][SIZE], int mat2[][SIZE], int result_mat[][SIZE])
{
    int i,j,k;
    for (i = 0; i <SIZE; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j <SIZE; ++j)
        {
            result_mat[i][j] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < SIZE; ++k)
                result_mat[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
                if(result_mat[i][j]!=0){
                    result_mat[i][j]=1;
                }
        }
    }



}

void print_mat(int mat[][SIZE],int size)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            printf("%3d", mat[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Please use the "%3d" format to print for uniformity.
}

int main()
{
    int mat1[][SIZE]={ 0 }, mat2[][SIZE]={ 0 }, res_mat[][SIZE]={0};
    printf("Please Enter Values For Matrix 1\n");
    read_mat(mat1,SIZE);

    printf("Please Enter Values For Matrix 2\n");
    read_mat(mat2,SIZE);

    mult_mat(mat1,mat2,res_mat);

    printf("The First Matrix Is :- \n");
    print_mat(mat1,SIZE);


    printf("The Second Matrix Is :- \n");
    print_mat(mat2,SIZE);

    printf("The Resultant Matrix Is :- \n");
    print_mat(res_mat,SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

The input and output should be like this:

```
Please Enter Values For Matrix 1
111000654987010
Please Enter Values For Matrix 2
11 53
The First Matrix Is :-
  1  1  1  0  0
  0  1  1  1  1
  1  1  0  1  0 
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0

The Second Matrix Is :-
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
The Resultant Matrix Is :-
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  0  0  0  0
  1  1  1  1  1
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
```

But when I run the program, this message appears:

> exception thrown: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'mat2' was corrupted.

and the output isn't right and I am getting some elements has a junk values:

```
Please Enter Values For Matrix 1
111000654987010
Please Enter Values For Matrix 2
11 53
The First Matrix Is :-
  1  1  1  0  0
  0  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1-858993460-858993460-858993460
-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460  1
The Second Matrix Is :-
  1  1  1  1  1
-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460
-858993460-858993460  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
The Resultant Matrix Is :-
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
```

Another question:

if I entered to the mat1 a big string it's calculated directly without letting me enter a string to mat2 how do I solve this problem ?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and they will tell you the problem. Or at least part of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int mat1[][SIZE]={ 0 }
```

will declare a 1x5 matrix. Change it to

```
int mat1[SIZE][SIZE]={ 0 }
```

Comment: ok and another question if I entered to the first a big string it's calculated directly without letting me enter a string to mat2 how do I solve this problem ?